# How to Google token-based authentication in gRPC?

Tags: c++, grpc

I implemented a Server using SSL like:

```
grpc::SslServerCredentialsOptions sslOpts{};
sslOpts.pem_key_cert_pairs.push_back(
       grpc::SslServerCredentialsOptions::PemKeyCertPair{
         readFile("../openssl/server.key"),
         readFile("../openssl/server.crt")});
auto creds = grpc::SslServerCredentials(sslOpts);
```

and a Client using SSL like:

```
sslOpts.pem_root_certs = readFile("../openssl/server.crt");
sslOpts.pem_private_key = readFile("../openssl/client.key");
sslOpts.pem_cert_chain = readFile("../openssl/client.crt");
auto creds = grpc::SslCredentials(sslOpts);
builder.AddListeningPort(address, creds);
```

This works fine, but now I have to use token-based authentication(based on the given task) and explain the difference. I don't know how to set up the server and the client nether.

Answer (score 0):

This doc contains more details and examples on how to use token based authentication:
https://grpc.io/docs/guides/auth/